# bzr error when trying to branch code

Tags: bazaar

For example when I run the command `bzr branch lp:totem`, I am getting error

```
gaurav@gaurav-HCL-ME-Laptop:~/bzr$ bzr branch lp:totem
You have not informed bzr of your Launchpad ID, and you must do this to
write to Launchpad or access private data.  See "bzr help launchpad-login".
bzr: ERROR: Target directory "" already exists.
```

The present working directory is empty. I've tried on two systems, both running 12.04 and I'm getting the same result.

Answer (score 1):

This was a regression in one of the beta releases of bzr 2.5. It should be fixed in 2.5b6.

See http://pad.lv/919218 for the bug report.